# How to pass data child to child widget without rebuild parent widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I have one `ParentWidget` having two child widget.
I want to pass some callback action from `FirstChild()` to `SecondChild()` Widget without rebuild `ParentWidget()`like `setState((){})`.

I want to do because `ParentWidget()` has many widget. And this callback action continuously happen.

And continuously `setState((){})` is not viable option for `ParentWidget()`

For example

`setState((){})` call from `FirstChild()` than I want to rebuild `SecondChild()` without rebuild `ParentWidget()`

Answer (score 0):

`StatefulWidget` is only useful in very simple business logic cases. I highly recommend that you have a look at [`Riverpod`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod), where you can access a "state" from any widget, regardless of who its parent widget is. And because of how Riverpod is designed, it will not trigger any unnecessary rebuilds.

Sticking with `StatefulWidget`, you will need to use something like `InheritedWidget` as a parent of both widgets, and then have them both access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help with state management solutions like Provider or Riverpod.
I may write an example code if you use Riverpod, but generally speaking, in such case, you need to place the state outside the Parent widget into some external variable. Then you can access and share it between both Children without rebuilding Parent.